# Как связать БД mongodb и приложение на NodeJS в Jelastic?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

После регистрации на reg.ru создал окружение с NodeJS и добавил mongodb. Пришла информация с данными для подключения.
Имя хоста, пароль, логин.

Открываю соединение через mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect('
  mongodb://login:password@mongodb148973-nodejs.jelastic.regruhosting.ru/bd');
```

Запускаю и вижу следующую картину:

```
nodejs@node148974-nodejs /home/jelastic/ROOT/seed $ node product-seeder.js
(node:608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at /home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:595:61
    at authenticateStragglers (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:513:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:549:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:599:20)
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:65:17)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:109:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:7)
(node:608) MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at /home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:595:61
    at authenticateStragglers (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:513:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:549:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:599:20)
(node:608) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:92:15)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:109:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:7)
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Оказалось все просто. Нужно добавить номер порта 27017: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://login:password@mongodb148973-nodejs.jelastic.regruhosting.ru:27017/bd');`